# Prime ideals over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $K$ be a field, then $O_K=\{a\in K : a\text{ is a zero of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients}\}.$

Consider the ring $\mathbb Z$ and $O_K$. If $q$ is a prime ideal in $O_K$, then $q\cap\mathbb Z$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb Z$, hence $q\cap\mathbb Z=p\mathbb Z$, for some prime number $p$.

My two questions are:

1. Why is it true that there are only finitely many prime ideals $q$ in $O_K$ such that $q\cap \mathbb Z=p$, for a fixed prime number $p$?
2. Why is $O_K/q$ a finite algebraic extension of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$? I guess it has something to do with that fact that $O_K$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z-$module, right?

Thanks :)

Comment: You mean a **monic** polynomial with integer coefficients. Otherwise $O_{\mathbb Q}$ would contain $\frac 12$.

Comment: You do *not* mean for *K* to be an arbitrary field. If $K = \mathbf C$ then the premise of both of your questions is wrong, since your ring $O_K$ would be all algebraic integers in $\mathbf C$, in which case there are infinitely many prime ideals $q$ and the field $O_K/q$ is not a finite extension of the integers mod $p$.

Comment: Anyway, have you looked in an algebraic number theory book? Both of your questions are standard results and would be found in many such books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you assume $K$ to be a number field (i.e a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$). These are classical results about number fields:

1) The set of prime ideals $q$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ containing $p$ is in bijection with the set of prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$.
You may know that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice of rank $n=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$, i.e.
$\mathcal{O}_K\simeq \mathbb{Z}^n$, so 
$$\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n,$$
which shows that $\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$ is a finite ring, thus has finitely many prime ideals.

2) We have an injection 
$\mathbb{F}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_K/q\mathcal{O}_K$, 
and a surjection $\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{O}_K/q$.
We showed at (1) that $\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$ is finite, hence $\mathcal{O}_K/q$ is a finite, integral ring, i.e., it's a field.

So it's a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: About 2) alone : For any $a \in \mathcal{O}_K$ (non-zero, non-unit) then $\mathcal{O}_K/(a)$ is a finite ring. Since $q$ is a prime ideal then $\mathcal{O}_K/q$ is an integral domain, and since it is a finite ring it is a finite field. $q \cap \mathbb{Z} = (p)$ means that $\mathcal{O}_K/q$ contains $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ as a subring, ie. it is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: Why can you say $q$ contains pOk$?